# running ant build in eclipse causing cpu to peak and remain at 50%

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I am launching eclipse with jdk 1.6_0.24  javaw.exe currently.  In the past I have tried the .dll and javaws.exe

All of these cause my machines CPU to go crazy and it never goes back down after running an ant build. CPU stays at at least 50%, if not higher.

I am running ant using the external tools.  I specify that ant should execute using a separate JRE.  I have tried 3 different JREs as the 'separate JRE'.  1)  the same jre used to launch eclipse 2) jdk 1.6_0.22  3)  jrockit_160_14_R27.6.25-32.

A build that takes roughly 2 minutes on my co-workers machine is taking 9,10,11,12 minutes on mine b/c the CPU is maxed out at times and can't switch contexts.
My eclipse becomes nearly unusable afterwards and I have to restart eclipse.

Has anyone else seen this happen?  Any solutions?

Comment: What does eclipse do - never ending validation of JSF or XML?

Answer (score 0):

What is java heap size configured in eclipse.ini? 
You may want to tweak based on your project requirement as default values are low for large projects